# How to include Android-SlideExpandableListView with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to use Android-SlideExpandableListView in a project with gradle/Android Studio. Although the author says “Add the library as a gradle dependency to your project.” in the README, he doesn’t give instructions on how to include it properly. Issue filed here: https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView/issues/74

The best I've found so far is this [fork](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.sephiroth.android.library.fork.slideexpandable/slideexpandable/1.0.3.1), but I’m not sure it's quite the same:

```
compile(group: 'it.sephiroth.android.library.fork.slideexpandable', name: 'slideexpandable', version: '1.0.3.1', ext: 'aar')
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be author to upload it to Maven or JCenter.
That "fork" that you found - is uploaded by somebody else that was so kind that didn't wan't to reserve original name and cause misunderstanding in future.

So, best way is to create issue at repo (as is already made) and wait for author to upload library to Maven/JCenter - or upload by yourself (but please make such name to make it visible that it isn't a official one).

Hope it helps.